# Obtaining tickmark vector or intervals in R - par("yaxp") not working

Tags: r, plot, axis

I have a log-log plot displaying tick marks on the y-axis from 1 to 7. I would like to obtain the interval between each tickmark for a function.

```
> par("yaxp")
[1]  1  7 -6
```

I was expecting par("yaxp")[3] to be 1.

Why is it -6? How can I get R to return the interval between tickmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the other help , when log is used the signification of `xaxp` is a little bit different. But here since the n is negative we still in the linear case. In other works the distance  between steps is

```
 (1-7)/(-6) = 1
```

You can use `axTicks` to get the ticks used internally by `axes` to plot the ticks. Here an example modified from the help of `axTicks` to show you diffrenet values of `n`:

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(4, 1))
for(x in 9999 * c(1/99999,1, 2, 8)) {
  plot(x, 9, log = "x")
  cat(formatC(par("xaxp"), width = 5),";", T <- axTicks(1),"\n")
  rug(T, col =  adjustcolor("red", 0.5), lwd = 4)
}
par(op)

 ## n negative (your case): linear case 
 0.05  0.25    -4 ; 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 
 ## n =3 :     k 10^j with k in {1,2,5} & j in par("usr")[1:2]
 1000 1e+05     3 ; 200 500 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000 1e+05 2e+05 5e+05 
 ## n =2     k 10^j with k in {1,5} & j in par("usr")[1:2]
 1000 1e+06     2 ; 500 1000 5000 10000 50000 1e+05 5e+05 1e+06 
 ## n =1 :  10^j with j in par("usr")[1:2]
 1000 1e+07     1 ; 1000 10000 1e+05 1e+06 1e+07
```

Answer (score 1):

this is definitely to do with the fact it is a log scale

from the `?par` documentation:

> xaxp - 
>   A vector of the form c(x1, x2, n) giving the coordinates of the
>   extreme tick marks and the number of intervals between tick-marks when
>   par("xlog") is false. Otherwise, when log coordinates are active, the
>   three values have a different meaning: For a small range, n is
>   negative, and the ticks are as in the linear case, otherwise, n is in
>   1:3, specifying a case number, and x1 and x2 are the lowest and
>   highest power of 10 inside the user coordinates, 10 ^ par("usr")[1:2].
>   (The "usr" coordinates are log10-transformed here!)

see:

```
x<-1:100
y<-1:100
plot(x,y,log="y")
par("yaxp")
par("ylog")
```

compared to

```
plot(log(x),log(y))
par("ylog")
par("yaxp")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

So the first thing I got wrong is: for a non log plot par("yaxp")[3] is "the number of intervals between tick-marks" so to get interval spacing I would need to do par("yaxp")[2]/par("yaxp")[3]

Still unsure how to obtain the interval for a log-log plot but I think I can work around it using par("yaxp")[1] just to get the first tick mark